# mongodb iterate over array elements without unwind

Tags: mongodb, unwind

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    c: [
      {
        d: [
          {
            b: [
              {
                a: 1
              },
              {
                a: 2
              },
              {
                a: 2
              },
              {
                a: 2
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

We have this sample data and the question is
// count() how many are the "c.d.b.a":2 in the collection
// Final result: {"a":3}
We can do it with unwind but the data is very big and unwind operation performance not good for big collections. Is there any other solution to this problem.
[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LHg_1Y0jd9-)

I have tried it with unwind but finding another solution without unwind operator

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/svQxI-AHprq

Comment: Thanks but final result should be 3 because we have this condition "c.d.b.a":2

Comment: ok i have changed cond part to this and it is working
thanks a lot
$eq: [
                                      "$$this.a",
                                      2
                                    ]